# Neither .bashrc or .bash_profile appear to be executing when I open a new terminal

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

When I open a new terminal window, neither of these scripts seem to run. Where is it set for these scripts to run anyway? If I manually run `source ~/.bashrc` then I see the changes that I have configured in there (e.g. colors)

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

`man bash` says (in part) under **INVOCATION**

```
   When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-inter‐
   active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
   mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
   that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
   in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
   exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the
   shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

   When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
   reads and executes commands from  /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc,  if
   these  files  exist.  This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.
   The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and  execute  commands
   from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.
```

Make sure your `.bashrc` has the execute bit set.

```
chmod +x $HOME/.bashrc
```